# Best way to create a temp table with column's data as header of table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need to create a temp table with column's data as header of  table. What is the best way to do it?

create table #Temp (

select distinct(Grade) from LoadingSheet

)

Comment: This sounds like an [XY Problem](//xyproblem.info), why do you "need" to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need to use a Global Temp Table (note the double hash), or a real table, because otherwise a temp table created inside the DynamicSQL session is only accessible within that same session.

Also be careful to ensure that your query only returns one row.

```
DECLARE @SQL NVARCHAR(MAX) = ''

SELECT DISTINCT @SQL =  'CREATE TABLE ##Temp
('+QUOTENAME(Grade)+' NVARCHAR(255))'
FROM dbo.LoadingSheet 

EXEC(@SQL)

SELECT * FROM ##Temp
```